# Passing Foreach data from PHP to Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hoping someone can help with this code.  I have a php file with a foreach loop to get data from mysql database.  When the user clicks Update in the php file, this JS script is called.  I am using a "this" to get an individual set of values.  The issue I am having is that nothing is getting passed to the JS script.

Here is the PHP code and it the PHP code works as it is tested with echo statements.

```
<?php
$artist_about_already = artist_news_check($artist_id);
if ($artist_about_already == true) { 
    $artist_news = (get_artist_news_all($artist_id));   
foreach ($artist_news as $news) {
    $news_id     = $news['id'];
    $timestamp = $news['timestamp'];
    $title     = $news['title'];
    $news      = $news['news'];
    $news_timestamp = date('D M d Y @ h:i:s', $timestamp);
?>
<div class="well no-padding">
  <form action="" method="post" name="artist_update_news" id="artist_update_news" class="smart-          form client-form">

                                <fieldset>
                                <section>
 <strong>Posted on:  <?php echo $news_timestamp ?></strong>

                                    <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                                        <input type="text" name="artist_update_news_title"       id="artist_update_news_title" value="<?php echo  $title ?>">
                                        <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Needed to update   Artist News</b> </label>
                                </section>
                            <section>
                                <label class="textarea">                                        
                                    <textarea rows="5" maxlength="2000" name="artist_edit_news"    id="artist_edit_news"><?php echo $news ?></textarea> 
                                </label>
                            </section>
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" id ="hiddenId"  value="<?php echo $news_id; ?>">

                            </fieldset>

                            <footer>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success updateBtn"    href="#artist_news.php" id="<?php echo $id ?>">
                                    Update
                                </button>

                            </footer>
                            </form>
                    </div>

  <?php
     }  
    } 

   ?>
```

When the user clicks Update on any of the individual records in the foreach statement, the following code is called.

```
runAllForms();
$(function () {    
$("#artist_update_news").validate({
rules: {
  artist_update_news_title : {
  required : true
  },
 artist_edit_news : {
 required : true
 }
 },
        // messages for form validation
 messages : {
 artist_update_news_title : {
 required : 'Please enter your News Heading'
 },
 artist_edit_news : {
 required : 'Please enter your News'
 }
 },

 errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
 error.insertAfter(element.parent());
 },
submitHandler: function() {
alert('in function');
var element = $(this);
var hiddenId = element.attr("hiddenId");
var artist_edit_news = element.attr("artist_edit_news");
var artist_update_news_title = element.attr("artist_update_news_title");
alert(hiddenId);
alert(artist_edit_news);
alert(artist_update_news_title);
 $('#artist_update_news').hide(0);
 $('#art_edit_news_message').hide(0);

$.ajax({
 url : 'artist_edit_news.php',
 type : 'POST',
 dataType : 'json',
 data: {
 artist_update_news_title : artist_update_news_title.val(),
 artist_edit_news : artist_edit_news.val(),
 hiddenId : hiddenId.val()
 },
 success : function(data){
 $('#art_edit_news_message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
 .text(data.msg).show(500);
 if (data.error === true) {
    if (data.goto == 1) {
    window.location = "http://dev.worldmusicstage.com/main.php#/ajax/artist_news.php";
    $('#artist_update_news').show(500);
         delete json;
    }
    else {

    $('#artist_update_news').show(500);
    }
}
 if (data.error === false) {
    window.location = "http://dev.worldmusicstage.com/main.php#/ajax/artist_news.php";
    $('#artist_update_news').show(500);
 delete json;
 }
 },
 error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 $('#art_edit_news_message').removeClass().addClass('error')
alert('The error was: '+errorThrown);
alert('The error was: '+XMLHttpRequest);
alert('The error was: '+textStatus);
alert(errorThrown.stack)
$('#artist_update_news').show(500);
 }
 });
return false;
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need generate a unique dynamic id for input tag in

```
id ="hiddenId"
```

We also need to set the value of variable **$id** in

```
<button 
        type="submit" 
        class="btn btn-success updateBtn"
        href="#artist_news.php"
        id="<?php echo $id ?>"
 >
```

You need generate a unique dynamic id for input tag or use a class selector in

```
$("#artist_update_news").validate({
```

and in

```
<form action=""
      method="post" 
      name="artist_update_news"
      id="artist_update_news"
      class="smart-form client-form">
```

Comment: Thanks, I did make a revision to the submit button.  The ID was wrong and I updated it to $news_id.  But, still not working.               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success updateBtn" href="#artist_news.php" id="<?php echo $news_id ?>">

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  I am a bit confused on how to do this.  If I specify in the form ID a unique id, how then do I specify that Id in the script.  As I loop through the foreach, I can assign 1, 2, 3, 4, etc for a unique ID instead of artist_update_news, but then how do I identify this in the script.  OR do I reference as getelementbyid.  Thanks for your help.  Grant